# How to get XML data posted by CURL in codeigniter?

Tags: xml, codeigniter, post, curl

Basically the work-flow is as follows:

1) Some 3rd party device will send / post XML data in via curl as follows:
       curl --data-ascii ~/Desktop/abc.xml http://my-site.com/my-controller/my-function

2) In 'my-function', I have to check if some data has been posted or not. And then conditionally perform the action.

XML format in abc.xml is as follows

```
<root-node>
      <node>
          <a>xxx</a>
      </node>
      <node>
          <a>xxx</a>
      </node>
      <node>
           <a>xxx</a>
      </node>
   </root-node>
```

The point is how to check if XML data has been posted or not and if posted then how to retrieve it. Like in CI we generally used to do $this->input->post('variable'). But here no 'variable' is present as posted data is XML ie I don't have way of referring posted data.

So, please suggest how to proceed.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to build and retrieve html/xml documents

Similar to javascript you could use `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't solve my problem. Actually I just want a mean to grab that XML data that is POSTed. Further processing of XML is different part, which I can manage.

Comment: You will need to process the xml doc first, like I say use getElementsByTagName(loop) and see if any element(node) exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

For more info about DOMDocument look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php